# Why MySQL (MariaDB) update transaction returns '0 row affected'?

Tags: mysql, transactions, mariadb

- Hello everyone.

I have something weird with MySQL.
(Oh, first of all, sorry for my poor English.)

I've made the simple table and stored procedure. Table definition is...

```
CREATE TABLE numTable (
    firstNum INT,
    secondNum INT
);
INSERT INTO numTable (firstNum, secondNum) VALUES (1, 2);
```

and the SP is...

```
DELIMITER ;;

CREATE PROCEDURE updateNum (
    IN num1 INT,
    IN num2 INT
)

BEGIN

START TRANSACTION;

    UPDATE  numTable
    SET     firstNum = num1, secondNum = num2;

COMMIT;

END ;;

DELIMITER ;
```

Then I executed the SP like this...

```
CALL updateNum (3, 4);
```

And MySQL returns ...

> 0 row(s) affected

When I saw this result, I thought 'Is there any syntax error?' But, no. UPDATE query worked fine. numTable's data changed from (1, 2) to (3, 4).

And I also found this. I removed the 'START TRANSACTION;' and 'COMMIT' statement. and execute updateNum SP again. The result was ...

> 1 row(s) affected

This time, UPDATE query worked fine too. numTable's data has successfully changed.

Why this difference has happen? Is there a way I can get a right affected rows with using TRANSACTION statement?

I tested this at MySQL 5.6.27, MariaDB 10.0.21 and MariaDB 10.1.8 and results are same as above.

Thank you for read my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will get the affected rows using

```
ROW_COUNT()
```

so, SELECT ROW_COUNT()
at the end

Comment: Thank you, Leow Kah Man. Your answer pretty helpful. But I want to know why this difference has happen. Can you teach me?

Comment: I must admit I am not the best teacher of theories. I can however say that you are getting 0 rows affected as an output from the COMMIT command, the last message of your stored procedure which is not the information that you want. What you wanted to know was what happened in the middle.

Answer (score 2):

similar to @Leow's, but I have found that without a transaction, and without it happening immediately after the update, all is lost. So:

```
START TRANSACTION;
update ...
select row_count() into @theCount; -- saved for posterity, perhaps for use at end
COMMIT;
select @theCount;
```

Comment: It's the last command you executed that threw the 0. The commit